# Need to ignore proxy without disabling it on control panel

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7

I trying to run a hello world app on my device environment using ga and Python, however even not doing any explicit url request, the urllib2 is having some problems with my proxy server.

I tried adding the localhost to the list of exclusion and it didn't work. If I disable the proxy on machine it works perfectly.

How can I make it work without disabling the proxy  for all programs?

Comment: Please provide a snippet of the code you are using so that we can see what might be happening.

Comment: I'm using just a self.response.write. It is a hello world app only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution here was to use CNTLM (http://cntlm.sf.net/), which creates kind of new proxy and handles the authentication process automatically.

Answer (score 0):

If you are running your app from the terminal, using dev_appserver.py try using the --skip_sdk_update_check switch, it may be the SDK update check that is failing.

Comment: I'm already using it. The error seems to be related to the url handling by the routing feature and the corporate proxy with authentication.